# Aplicando efeito ao scrollar mouse

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugin

Separei meu site por sessões:

```
<section id="parte1"></section>
<section id="parte2"></section>
<section id="parte3"></section>
```

E gostaria de aplicar um efeito quando eu scrollar o mouse, tipo assim 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/02/loading-effects-for-grid-items-with-css-animations/

Meu layout é um pouco diferente do deste demo do plugin, pois não tenho imagens conforme está ali.

Eu teria que colocar as `<section>` dentro dos `li`? Conforme exemplo do plugin:

```
<ul class="grid effect-4" id="grid">
    <li><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMM"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://drbl.in/fWPV"><img src="images/2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://drbl.in/fWMT"><img src="images/3.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://drbl.in/fQdt"><img src="images/4.png"></a></li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Filipe votei para fechar por questão de organização pois acho que a pergunta a que referí resolve o teu problema. Assim precisas só de ajustar o código que lá está na resposta. Se criares um jsFiddle posso ajudar a afinar.

Comment: esta aqui: http://codepen.io/claviska/pen/cybdG

Comment: @Sergio ficou um tanto complicado vendo a sua explicação

Comment: @FelipeStoker viste o jsFiddle na resposta? consegues adaptar para o teu caso?

Comment: @Sergio no meu caso não tenho `p` quero que seja direto no `<section>`, peguei esse JSFiddle que você fez http://jsfiddle.net/4fxXb/

Comment: @FelipeStoker coloca o teu HTML. Se não conseguires pôr a funcionar com o teu HTML e adaptando o meu JS/jQuery coloca aqui que ajudo. Mas tens de colocar o teu HTML e tentar...